Is there any way to configure Swagger to pickup documentation attributes from interface methods
I'm using Swagger to generate API documentation for .NET web application I'm currently working on. Out of the box, it works fine for recognizing most of the annotation attributes. But this works only for concrete controller methods. When I move some (or all) attributes from controller to its interface method, it won't pick it up. I wanted to try and move bulk of attributes from endpoint method implementations to their interfaces, thus make controllers' implementation files more readable and easier to navigate.
So this works:
public class ControllerA()
{
   [Produces("application/json")]
   [HttpGet]
   public ActionResult<string> MethodA()
   {
       ...
   }
}

Produces attribute will be picked up and used for generating documentation.
But this won't work:
interface IControllerA()
{
   [Produces("application/json")]
   public ActionResult<string> MethodA();
}

public class ControllerA() : IControllerA
{
   [HttpGet]
   public ActionResult<string> MethodA()
   {
       ...
   }
}

There is an option for implementing class with IOperationFilter, and use it to configure Swagger on application startup. This gives ability to implement custom logic for picking attributes during documentation build, but doesn't seem straightforward nor trivial. I would prefer just telling Swagger to do the same thing it already does, just expand it to interface methods (if possible).
